# Using linq to filter out list

Tags: c#, list, filter

I have a file and I have read all lines using 
    List lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
the list is something like this:

```
Remove lines here
...
BEGIN READ
X
Y
Z
END READ
more lines to remove
...
```

I want to keep the section between "BEGIN READ" and "END READ" not including those triggers.
How do I filter out those lines?

Comment: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Comment: I have tried loops and if it hits "BEGIN READ" it set a bool to true and if it hits "END READ" it set that bool to false. But I'm more interested in trying to do this with linq  functions such as "where and select"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(fname)
                .SkipWhile(line => line != "BEGIN READ")
                .TakeWhile(line => line != "END READ")
                .Skip(1)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Enumerable.SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx) and [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) to handle this:

```
var linesOfInterest = lines
                        .SkipWhile(l => l != "BEGIN READ")
                        .Skip(1)
                        .TakeWhile(l => l != "END READ");
```

This will return the lines between those two tags.  The extra `Skip(1)` is there to skip the actual `"BEGIN READ"` line itself.